# Isn't there a nicer way to combine multiple `Union{T, Nothing}`

Tags: julia, option-type, lazy-evaluation

I'm very new to Julia but I've got a some background in Scheme/Rust/F#.

Today I wanted to make [yesterday's AoC](https://adventofcode.com/2020/day/1) nicer without an explicit number of nested loops.

I arrived at this working solution, but I don't like the last `if`. In the languages mentioned above I would call a function (or use a computation expression) that gives me the first result that is not `None`. For Julia, I expected [something](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/base/base/#Base.something) to do that. It *does*, but unexpectedly in an eager fashion.

So When I tried `return something(find(r, n, start + 1, which), find(r, n - 1, start + 1, extended))`, that also evaluated the second argument when the first already had a result—and thus crashed.

Is there a macro/lazy version or `something` that I didn't find? How are you supposed to handle a case like that?

I also thought about (short-circuited) or'ing them together, but I guess Julia's strictness in that matter spoils that.

```
using DataStructures

function find(r::Array{Int}, n, start = 1, which = nil())::Union{Int,Nothing}
    if start <= length(r)
        extended = cons(start, which)
        with_current = sum(i -> r[i], extended)
        if with_current == 2020 && n == 1
            return prod(i -> r[i], extended)
        else
            # Unfortunately no :(
            #return something(find(r, n, start + 1, which), find(r, n - 1, start + 1, extended))
            re = find(r, n, start + 1, which)
            if isnothing(re)
                return find(r, n - 1, start + 1, extended)
            else
                re
            end
        end
    end
end
```

Comment: I fear there is no solution as nice as a monad. But you'd be in the same situation in Scheme, right?

Comment: this could be handled by writing a `@something` macro that would be lazy.

Comment: @phipsgabler Yes, in Scheme I would use a macro for that. Part of the question was is there already one for Julia.

Comment: According to @BogumiłKamiński, the answer seems to be “no”. I would have thought this is such a common case that there has to be one.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let me comment more on it why it is not possible given the discussion in the comments.

In Julia function arguments are evaluated eagerly, so Julia evaluates both `find(r, n, start + 1, which)` and `find(r, n - 1, start + 1, extended)` before passing them to `something` function.

Now, with macros you have (I am not writing in a fully general case for simplicity and I hope I got the hygiene right :)):

```
julia> macro something(x, y)
           quote
               local vx = $(esc(x))
               isnothing(vx) ? $(esc(y)) : vx
           end
       end
@something (macro with 1 method)

julia> @something 1 2
1

julia> @something nothing 2
2

julia> @something 1 sqrt(-1)
1

julia> @something nothing sqrt(-1)
ERROR: DomainError with -1.0:
sqrt will only return a complex result if called with a complex argument. Try sqrt(Complex(x)).
```

(in a full-blown version of the macro varargs and `Some` should be handled to replicate `something` exactly)

Comment: Maybe worth filing an issue to discuss adding this!

Answer (score 0):

Piqued by Bogumił's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65126462/581002) I wanted to write my first Julia macro. It took some time and numerous attempts to figure out syntax, hygiene and escaping but I'm quite happy now.

I thought it might be worth sharing and provide opportunity for suggestions/improvements.

#### A lazy `@something` analog to `Base.something`

```
function _something_impl(thing)
    :(something($(esc(thing))))
end

function _something_impl(thing, rest...)
    quote
        local evalued = $(esc(thing))
        if isnothing(evalued)
            $(_something_impl(rest...))
        else
            something(evalued)
        end
    end
end

macro something(things...)
    _something_impl(things...)
end
```

#### Version without exceptions

As I found exceptions raised from a macro like this not quite suitable, I also made a version that falls back to `nothing`.

```
function _something_nothing_impl(thing)
    quote
        local evaluated = $(esc(thing))
        if isa(evaluated, Some)
            evaluated.value
        else
            evaluated
        end
    end
end

function _something_nothing_impl(thing, rest...)
    quote
        local evalued = $(esc(thing))
        if isnothing(evalued)
            $(_something_nothing_impl(rest...))
        else
            something(evalued)
        end
    end
end

macro something_nothing(things...)
    _something_nothing_impl(things...)
end
```

Now I guess the recursive middle function could *also* generated by a macro. :)